# Unable to Import Django Application into uWSGI

Tags: django, google-compute-engine, uwsgi

On my Google Compute Engine instance, I have been trying to setup my application server (uWSGI) following these steps:

1. cd /path/to/project/directory
2. workon virtual_env
3. uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

Every time I initialize uWSGI, the following error is thrown (a more extensive log below):

```
ImportError: No module named '"adtor'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I'm able to run the development server alone (python manage.py runserver).  It is peculiar that there is an extra double quote (") before my django application's name, but am unable to find any instances of an extra double quote within code, the .ini, virtual env hooks (e.g. postactivate).  Beyond this, I'm unable to find a potential culprit; I'd assume it is either within my .ini file or improperly installed some third-party library.

"pip freeze":

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.8.5
django-filter==1.0.2
django-model-utils==3.0.0
djangorestframework==3.6.2
mysqlclient==1.3.10
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
uWSGI==2.0.15
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:8000
stats=127.0.0.1:9191
http-timeout=1800

uid=www-data
gid=www-data

virtualenv=/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod
home=/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod
chdir=/srv/django/adtor_project/prime
module=adtor.wsgi:application
master=true
vacuum=true
thunder-lock=true
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/adtor-blog.log

threads=2
enable-threads=true

for-readline = /etc/srv/vars.txt
  env = %(_)
endfor =
```

Log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Fri May  5 16:00:56 2017] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 02 May 2017 17:47:17
os: Linux-4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017
nodename: instance-1
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /srv/django/adtor_project
writing pidfile to /tmp/project-master.pid
detected binary path: /home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /srv/django/adtor_project/prime
your processes number limit is 2257
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: enabled
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000 fd 3
Python version: 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:12:14)  [GCC 4.8.4]
Set PythonHome to /home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1a02ab0
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 166112 bytes (162 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./adtor/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '"adtor'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8753)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8755, cores: 2)
*** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:9191 fd: 10 ***
```

Comment: This extra `"` story looks like [The double quotes were not proper double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811318/unable-to-import-django-application-into-uwsgi), i.e. `”` instead of `"`. Even if apparently not since your traceback does exhibit a real double quotes.

Comment: It appears I had correctly used double quotes.  I changed it to single quotes and received the error:

    ImportError: No module named "'adtor"

It seems as if the extra single/double quote has nothing to do with it

Comment: Is your `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "adtor.settings")` also correctly written  in the wsgi.py ?

Comment: Yes.  I have been using the default wsgi.py file, as in, have made zero changes to that file

Comment: Have you ever been able to run your production site ?

Comment: Not yet.  I've only been able to run the dev server via localhost and ssh port forwarded from my GCE instance

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer, but: note that not having a trailing slash makes unclear if your paths are files or directories. That being said, let us try considering your directories for what they are:

```
[uwsgi]
...
virtualenv=/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/
home=/home/tor/.virtualenvs/adtor_prod/
chdir=/srv/django/adtor_project/prime/
...
```

You may also try to add this line below `module=adtor.wsgi:application`

```
...
module=adtor.wsgi:application
env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=adtor.settings
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Within my uwsgi.ini file, I was loading incorrectly the settings module from another file. Instead of

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='adtor.settings.production'
```

I used

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=adtor.settings.production
```